# Get list of sites in SharePoint available to user

Tags: sharepoint, soap

I have been trying to use the sharepoint web service (from webs.asmx) GetWebCollection to get a list of the sites available to a user.  I have authenticated successfully with with sharepoint and if I hard code in the site path I can get files back.  However, when I try and use GetWebCollection I am given a "403 Forbidden" error?

What is required to be down differently?

Alternatively, is there any way to tell what site the user is automatically assigned to?

I am connecting via SOAP (with ASIHTTPRequest) in Objective-C.

```
- (void)getUrl {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://[server]/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx"];

requestGetSites = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[requestGetSites setDelegate:self];

NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<GetWebCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap\" />\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>";

[requestGetSites setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[requestGetSites setUsername:@"username"];
[requestGetSites setPassword:@"password"];
[requestGetSites appendPostData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestGetSites addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[requestGetSites addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"[a server]"];
[requestGetSites addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetWebCollection"];

NSLog(@"Request headers are: %@", [[requestGetSites requestHeaders] description]);

[requestGetSites startSynchronous];
```

}

Comment: Have you tried performing a POST request?

Comment: @woody993 is there any possibility to use ASIHTTPRequest without manual constructing of SOAP messages (wsdl2obj stubs)?

Comment: @surlac I last used wsdl2obj just over a year ago, since then I wrote a closed source library that constructs the XML payload using libxml, all requests are made using NSURLConnection and operation queues, and the responses are parsed using libxml into model objects. I then extended that library to construct the SharePoint specific SOAP methods and payloads. Depending on how much SharePoint/SOAP, and if you don't plan on using every WSDL method, doing this may be your best bet as well. So in the answer to your question, I am not entirely sure

Comment: @woody993 thanks. It would be awesome to look at your library, but it sounds like there is no possibility to share. Now I'm trying to use sudzc.com to generate stubs for request (it looks cleaner), but it doesn't generate a model to put the result into. So I'm thinking about saving every response in XML and generating a model from this resulting XML. Is it right way to do that?

Comment: @surlac I do have plans to open source it in the future, and will try and remember to let you know when I do, but it might not be for a few months. Regarding the models, that's the way I do, I read the XML and create model objects from that

Comment: @woody993, awesome! What tools do you use to automate the process of model generation for a new web-service?

Comment: Because I know the types of responses I get back from SharePoint, I  use a parent class (Implementation: https://gist.github.com/6ae61db7eeb578b3af84)
Then I subclass that and add properties as well as the mapping information (Implementation: https://gist.github.com/d2dbdb845de83ddbc91a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have open-sourced a SharePoint library that I use to connect to SharePoint available at http://github.com/woodnathan/SPConnector